# missing argument in php function?

Tags: php

Ok no i am calling a few variables from mysql database and they are not static i not that good but if i call a function like

```
$var = 'hi';

function fun($var){
         $var;
}
```

now it will be correct and display the result but if i call multiple variables from mysql database then it will show missing argument or variable not defined why so? I have define the result in more separate variables like

```
$row_data['value'] = $var;


function fun($var){
         $var;
}
```

now can anyone help me?

Comment: Approximately as clear as mud.

Comment: Please show more code. How are you calling `fun()` and what exactly is it complaining about?

Comment: Your function, it does nothing. You should reread the first sections of the PHP manual. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change 
    $row_data['value'] = $var;

To:
    $var = $row_data['value'];

Comment: Well thanks for your try people but i got my answer and the answer is that you cannot call non static variables like variables from a database in a function it has to first detect the variable as global or as a static value.